# Formatting multiple classes and IDs

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS3 and while going through a layout, I noticed that when I try to add design to multiple sections and also classes/IDs, sometimes I have to have space between the section name and class/ID and sometimes I don't. Please see below, specially the ones in **bold**.

When I eliminate space and give space in the wrong place, the code doesn't work.

I want to know why this happens, how do I know when to give space or put them together?
Thanks!

```
@media(max-width:768px){
    **header #branding,**
    header nav,
    header nav li,
    **#newsletter h1**,
    #newsletter form,
    #boxes .box,
    **article#main-col**,
    **aside#sidebar**{
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Bold doesn't work in SO code block. Use CSS comments.

Comment: For CSS selectors please refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/ . In general, a space means it's a parent-child, while no space applies to the same element.

Comment: In addition to the w3.org spec Ondra mentioned, check some of the css selector tutorials online, [Beginner Concepts: How CSS Selectors Work](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/) for example.  css-tricks is a great resource for learning among many others.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are allowed anywhere. Multiple spaces are also allowed.
Combining things on one line is also no problem. But a word (selector, property or value) may not be broken. `text- align` (broken with space) is NOT allowed.

`article#main-col` (without space) selects the `<article id="main-col">`

`article  #main-col` (with space) selects an `<... id="main-col">` inside the `<article>`

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do `aside #sidebar` but it wasn't working, then I did `aside#sidebar` and it worked. Interesting.